# What is the best method of getting objects from a class that belong to the current user

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm just starting out with Parse (REST API) and would like to know the best method of getting private objects from a class that belong to the current user. As far as I see it, there are two options:

1/ Pass the user id in the query string - I thought this was bad practise though.

2/ Each object would have an ACL set - could I just hit the class endpoint and let the ACL's take care of things and just return the objects that belong to the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You potentially could just let the ACL handle things, using the user's session token. This requires public find access to be disabled, though.

It's also not ideal, as it can not utilize database indexes. Your database is going to find all objects that match your query and parse-server will filter out the ones that don't pass a CLP / ACL check. At scale, this could damage performance significantly. Do objects only belong to a single user? Consider storing the user's ID on the object, then you can query for all objects that match that ID, and you can index your database by that id for fast results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jake. It seems that

Comment: *stupid commenting rules, grrr.* Anyway, Thanks for the reply Jake. It seems that just letting ACL handle things isn't he best way of doing things. The class would contain objects created by various users - I just want to return the objects to the users that they have created. Querying using the user ID was what I originally thought was the best way of doing it, but I'm using the REST API and would have to include the user id as a url parameter - I thought this was bad practise from a security standpoint, and was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: As long as you're using SSL and all of your (particularly the sensitive) data is properly secured with ACLs and CLPs it shouldn't be an issue. I.e. you shouldn't be able to make requests for any private data without a session, so you can see who is making requests, and depending on your use case, that private data should probably only be accessible to the user who owns it. Familiarize yourself with the CLP / ACL flow. The current user's object id is passed around by the server quite frequently.

Comment: For a quick refresher, an object must first pass a CLP in order to interact with an object, and then pass that specific object's ACL. CLP's have a cool "Pointer Permissions" feature that allows the user pointer for a field to access data within a row, but that user must also then pass the object's ACL - being on a pointer permission doesn't implicitly pass the ACL.

Comment: This type of stuff is WAY easier to design in from the get-go rather than put in place on a full blown project. Trust me haha. Do it right from the start. ACL *all* the things. Very few classes should have no ACL / CLP modification at all. Make sure you know the difference between find and get permissions.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks very much for all the info Jake :)

Answer (score 0):

Jake's answer is spot on, but I couldn't resist trying it out using rest, so in case its helpful to anyone.....

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8378/1'

let sessionToken;
let userId;
let userPointer;

/**
 * This test will setup a user, get its sessionToken.
 * Create three objects.  Two with both a pointer to
 * our test user and an acl that only gives our user permission
 * to read them.  The third test object has no acl so anyone can
 * read it.
 *
 * We then test this setup with two tests:
 *
 * The first test does a rest query with our test user's
 * session token and a where clause to only get our test
 * user's objects.
 *
 * The second test makes an anonymous query to get all
 * of the test object.  We then verify that we only get
 * the one object that is not restricted to our test user.
 */
fdescribe('Get own objects', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    // create a user to test with
    request.post({
      uri: `${baseUrl}/users`,
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'test',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'rest',
      },
      json: true,
      body: {
        username: 'tester',
        password: 'test'
      }
    })
      .then((r) => {
        sessionToken = r.sessionToken;
        userId = r.objectId;
        userPointer = {
          __type: 'Pointer',
          className: '_User',
          objectId: userId
        };

        // making the acl in two steps so a prop can
        // be set from a variable. The user id was
        // returned in the response under 'objectId'
        const ACL = {};
        ACL[userId] = { read: true, write: true };

        return request.post({
          uri: `${baseUrl}/batch`,
          headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'test',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'rest',
            // add our test users sessionToken so the request is
            // made with her permissions.
            'X-Parse-Session-Token': sessionToken,
          },
          json: true,
          body: {
            requests: [
              {
                method: "POST",
                path: "/1/classes/Stuff",
                body: {
                  user: userPointer,
                  ACL  // <-- shorthand notation for ACL: ACL
                }
              },
              {
                method: "POST",
                path: "/1/classes/Stuff",
                body: {
                  user: userPointer,
                  ACL
                },
              },
              {
                method: "POST",
                path: "/1/classes/Stuff",
                body: {
                  // just an empty one so without ACL so we can make sure our where query is working.
                }
              },
            ]
          }
        })
      })
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail)
  });

  it('should be able to fetch our own objects', (done) => {
    // make sure our test user can get her own objects
    const where = {
      user: userPointer
    }
    request.post({
      uri: `${baseUrl}/Classes/Stuff`,
      json: {
        where,
        _method: 'GET'
      },
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'test',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'rest',
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': sessionToken,
      }
    })
    .then((response) => expect(response.results.length).toBe(2))
    .then(done)
    .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should fail to fetch objects that aren\'t ours', (done) => {
    // make sure a request not made by our test user doesn't return
    // our test user's objects.
    request.get({
      uri: `${baseUrl}/Classes/Stuff`,
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'test',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'rest',
      },
      json: true
    })
      .then((response) => expect(response.results.length).toBe(1))
    .then(done)
    .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```